# The program JustCause3.exe has encountered a serious problem

Tags: wine

I have installed the game Just Cause 3 but it won't seem to run. I run the launcher and it gives the program has encountered a serious problem error. I have searched for two days for a solution on the web but have found none yet.

I have installed the vcredist and couldn't figure out how to install the directx (something said Wine came with it). I have tried taking out the intro as that worked in another game. Nothing else I found seemed connected and/or didn't work.

Please help.

EDIT: For all of you who look onto this post, my dealings with WineHQ are at this link: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=28643&p=110699#p110699

Comment: This seems like more of a question for the WINE forums. https://forum.winehq.org/

Comment: @johnkieran there are 2,733 questions tagged wine.